# Symfony5 - form only refresh after submit

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a problem with my Symfony5 app.
After submit form the page refresh and nothing happens. What wrong is in the code below? I tried to debug it and check where Controller have some error but i can't find it. In the profiler i can't see query with INSERT, only SELECT.

TopicController:

```
/**
 * @param Request $request
 * @Route("/custom", name="custom")
 */
public function custom(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('title', TextType::class, [
            'label' => 'Tytuł tematu'
        ])
        ->add('description', TextareaType::class, [
            'label' => 'Opis tematu',
            'attr' => [
                'rows' => 5,
                'placeholder' => 'Opis tematu...'
            ]
        ])
        ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, [
            'attr' => [
                'class' => 'btn btn-success btn-block'
            ],
            'label' => 'Zarezerwuj'
        ])
        ->add('category', ChoiceType::class, [
            'choices' => [
                'PWA' => 'PWA',
                'RWA' => 'RWA',
                'SPA' => 'SPA',
                'RIA' => 'RIA',
                'REST' => 'REST',
                'PHP REST' => 'PHP REST',
                'Inna' => 'Inna'
            ],
            'label' => 'Kategoria'
        ])
        ->add('techDescription', TextType::class, [
            'label' => 'Opis technologii',
            'attr' => [
                'placeholder' => 'Opis technologii...'
            ],
            'required' => FALSE
        ])
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $form->getErrors();

    $topic = new Topic();
    $reservation = new Reservation();

    if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $data = $form->getData();
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();


            $topic->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime());
            $topic->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime());
            $topic->setCustom(TRUE);
            $topic->setTitle($data['title']);
            $topic->setTopicDescription($data['topicDescription']);

            $em->persist($topic);
            $em->flush();

            $reservation->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime());
            $reservation->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime());
            $reservation->setUser($this->getUser());
            $reservation->setCategory($data['category']);
            if (!empty($data['techDescription']))
                $reservation->setTechDescription($data['techDescription']);
            $reservation->setTopic($topic);

            $em->persist($reservation);
            $em->flush();

            if ($reservation->getId() == NULL) {
                $em->remove($topic);
                $em->flush();

                $this->addFlash('error', 'Posiadasz już aktywną rezerwację');
                return $this->redirectToRoute('topic.custom');
            }

            return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
            
        } else {

            $this->addFlash('error','Issue with validation');
        }
    }

    return $this->render('topic/custom.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
```

custom.html.twig:

```
{% extends('base.html.twig') %}

{% block content %}

    <div class="container mt-4 mb-4 pl-4 pr-4">
        <form class="col-md-6 mx-auto" method="" action="">
            <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ csrf_token('custom') }}"/>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form_row(form.title) }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form_row(form.description) }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form_row(form.category) }}


                <div class="mt-3" id="techDesc" style="display:none">
                    {{ form_row(form.techDescription) }}
                </div>
            </div>
            {{ form_row(form.submit) }}
        </form>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: there are some good guides for symfony and symfony forms. You apparently missed them all, which makes me sad. for example `method=""` doesn't make any sense at all. how about POST? forms by default have csrf-protection, but you don't use form tags to build the <form>, so the csrf-protection is missing. for the closing `<form>` at least use `{{ form_end(form) }}` which will output all missing form fields (specifically the csrf protection) also, symfony provides a profiler, where you can look at the form data submitted and its validation.

Comment: @Jakumi, thank you for tips - problem solved by adding post to method, btw. csrf protection isn't missing, there is hidden input with csrf_token

Comment: oh, skipped over it, it seems ;o)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing `{{ form_start(form) }}` and `{{ form_end(form) }}`

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
//form
{{ form_end(form) }}
```